# How to Copy RDS snapshot from one region to another region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

"SourceRegion": "us-east-1",
"SourceDBSnapshotIdentifier": "test-fixer-12-07-2018-22-55-22",
"TargetDBSnapshotIdentifier": "test-fixer-12-07-2018-22-55-22-copied",

I want to copy snapshot from us-east-1 to us-west-2 using boto3 only but It is copied in us-east-1 only.
How to give destination region so that I am able to copy?

Comment: It is a PULL request.  So You must perform this task in the destination region.

Answer (score 2):

The region of your client -- the region you send the request to, as specified when creating the client object -- determines the destination region.  The destination, upon receiving your request, pulls the snapshot from the source region.

> You can copy a snapshot from one AWS Region to another. In that case, the AWS Region where you call the CopyDBSnapshot action is the destination AWS Region for the DB snapshot copy.
>
> https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.copy_db_snapshot